# WebPack: Change in module numbers do not change chunkhash

Tags: caching, webpack

I am using webpack to bundle my files into two file: app.js and lib.js and I create and append unique chunkhash for each of my files that get download by browser. Both these files are built together in the same build output. It would look like this:

```
lib.747c2ee515b25d871bd0.js
app.e6a0b36a5bb2bff41393.js
```

I have following caching set on these files:

```
Cache-Control:private, max-age=31536000
```

This means that these files will be cached for an year or when a new file arrives. And this would work independently for each file.

Since our application is closer to release, there more changes in `app` than in `lib`.

**Problem**: The problem I am facing is that in a new build, contents of the `lib` are not changed but module ids are changed. This is causing module ids to change but chunkhash doesn't change; causing downloading of `app` but not `lib` resulting into broken app. On Ctrl+F5 everything starts working again as expected.

**Questions**: Isn't the changed module ids considered as part of chunkash? How do I fix this problem? Is it possible to add auto-increment explicit version number to file names through WebPack?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I solved this is by adding one more number (which is `Date.now()`) into my file names as below.

```
filename: `[name].${Date.now().valueOf()}.[chunkhash].js`
```

This works pretty reliably for foreseeable time. This is with an understanding that the value returned by `Date.now().valueOf()` is the number of millisecond since midnight January 1, 1970 UTC. Besides, all I want to achieve here is the value be automatically generated and different from previous one.

The only drawback I see with this method is that: With each release, this forces all the bundles to be refreshed. However, this is not a so much of a concern considering very low frequency of production rollouts we will have after first 2 releases.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `webpack-md5-hash` plugin to change the webpack chunkhash then you might be hitting this [issue](https://github.com/erm0l0v/webpack-md5-hash/issues/7).

Also these two articles might help [Predictable long term caching](https://medium.com/webpack/predictable-long-term-caching-with-webpack-d3eee1d3fa31) and [Long term caching of static assets with webpack](https://medium.com/@okonetchnikov/long-term-caching-of-static-assets-with-webpack-1ecb139adb95).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am running into that issue. Unfortunately these solution wouldn't work for me and wouldn't cover all scenarios. :( PSB, how i resolved it.